# jQuery Mobile : How to change Radio button active state color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-fieldset, jquery-mobile-radio

How to change the radio button background color on selection?

```
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(e) {
    $("input[type='radio']").css('background-color', '#ff0000');
});
```

I have tried this..But it doesn't work.

---

Its not working.I forgot to share my code

> `<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="custom-fieldset">
>                 <span>Were you able to complete your visit today?</span><br/><input type="radio" id="radio_1134198__4516395"
>   name="sdid_1134198" value="radio_1134198__4516395" /><label
>   for="radio_1134198__4516395">Yes</label>`

I got the results like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDGeZ.png . Radio button color has to be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qkCZY/

## Version 1

**HTML :**

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="custom-fieldset">
        <legend>Horizontal:</legend>
        <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">One</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off" type="radio"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Two</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="other" type="radio"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-h-2c">Three</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#custom-fieldset div .ui-radio .ui-radio-on {
    background: red !important;
}
```

## Version 2

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/hTY6k/

**HTML :**

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="custom-fieldset"> 
    <legend>Were you able to complete your visit today?</legend>
    <label for="radio_1134198__4516395">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_1134198__4516395" name="sdid_1134198" value="radio_1134198__4516395"/>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS :**

```
#custom-fieldset div .ui-radio label span .ui-icon-radio-on {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

## Final notes

If you want to find more about how to customize jQuery Mobile page and widgets then take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**. It comes with a lot of working examples, including why is !important necessary for jQuery Mobile.